# Rated voltages for the Cage clamp connectors?

Tags: power, ac, connector, ratings, appliances

what does the rated voltage for a connector means? How should we select the connector for a 230V AC application?

Let us say can I use this connector for my 230V AV application?
[image]
https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/de/?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=1904969&library=dede&pcck=P-11-01-05&tab=1&selectedCategory=ALL#Materialangaben-Geh%C3%A4use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of the ratings are above 230 V, you should be okay to use that connector. Each of the different voltages given are the connectors rating under those specific test conditions (nominal & surge ratings).